# Can "immigrant" be used to refer to a "person who moves from rural area to city"?

Tags: meaning, nouns, word-usage

I have looked up the word 'immigrant': the definition refers to people who come to live in a different country.  Can I also use this word to refer to people who move from rural areas to the city?

Answer (score 13):

No, **immigrants** isn't normally used for people who move *within the same country* from rural to urban areas. But such people are often called [economic] **migrants**, or more specifically...

> **Rural migrants** are attracted by the possibilities that cities can offer, but often settle in shanty towns and experience extreme poverty. *(source: [Wikipedia article on **urbanisation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urbanization)).*

---

The relevant OED definition is...

> **migrant**: A person who moves permanently to live in ***a new country, town, etc.***, esp. to look for work, or to take up a post, etc.; an immigrant. *(italics mine)*

I interpret the last two words of the definition as meaning ***immigrants*** are one kind of **migrants** (specifically, the kind that move to a *different country*).

Comment: "The Great Migration" (1915 -1960) of Southern blacks to Northern cities in the U.S. is one example  of a big movement of people from rural to urban areas. http://www.blackpast.org/aah/great-migration-1915-1960 I generally think of migrants as part of a larger movement of people, e.g. "migrant workers".

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not really appropriate for that context.  The word [*immigrant*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/immigrant) formally means, as you said:

> a person who comes to a country to take up permanent residence

Someone who simply moves between locations within the same country [*relocates*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relocate) rather than *immigrates*.  I'm having trouble finding a good noun to describe someone who specifically moves from the country to the city, however.  The process as a whole is called [*urbanization*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/urbanization).

Comment: Jeff, so "urbanization" and "deruralization" mean the same thing?